# sql server 2000 using hint in view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

```
CREATE VIEW xxxx AS
SELECT order_date, 
       DATEPART(W, order_date) AS dayID, 
       Type 
  FROM dbo.Shipment_Dates 
 WHERE (TIP = 'normal') 
OPTION (FAST 20)
```

This create statment causes error at hint part .. Is there a workaround for adding hint to views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use query (OPTION) hints in a view.

A view is simply a macro that expands. The query hint would then be *internal* in the expansion because the view is then a subquery. And query hints are not allowed in subqueries.

Effectively, you'd have this:

```
select
   *
from
   (
   SELECT
     order_date, DATEPART(W, order_date) AS dayID, Type 
   FROM dbo.Shipment_Dates 
   WHERE (TIP = 'normal') 

   option (fast 20)  --not allowed
   ) WasAView
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx):

> Query hints can be specified only in the top-level query, not in subqueries.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of specifying the hint in the definition of the view, specify the hint when using the view:

```
select order_date, dayID, Type
    from xxxx
    option (fast 20)
```

Comment: couldn't thank you that that...thank you very very much..sorry for the delay.